# reCAPTCHA on second form submit not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

When users submit form, in php fields are validated. If there is some error php return echo message that there is an error (it doesn't return an ERROR to ajax). So the ajax is still "success".

If I comment `grecaptcha.reset();` in the ajax success, and when user submits the form for the second time then `$response != null && $response->success` returns `false` in php.

How to fix this, so that there is no `grecaptcha.reset()` after ajax successs, and that it is enough for user to pass the captcha for only once.

Here is the reCAPTCHA in the html form:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" style="display:inline-block;" data-sitekey="6LdDlHIUAAAAAD3hgpRSSsNpS7SaRILGNTNiyak_"></div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery('#some_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var FormData = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery('.buttonHolder').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery('#spinner-1').css('display', 'block');


jQuery.ajax({   

        url : rml_obj.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            action : 'some_form',
            security : rml_obj.check_nonce,
            data1 : FormData
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            PUM.open(7939);
            //alert(checkbox_chk);
            jQuery('.pum-content').html(response.message1);
            jQuery('.copy-url').html(response.message2);
            jQuery('.buttonHolder').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#spinner-1').css('display', 'none');
            //grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
            },

    });
});
```

And here is the php code for testing reCAPTCHA:

```
require_once "recaptchalib.php";
$secret = "6LdDlHIUAAAAALFlTOx-9T63cODtjs7eno******";
$response = null; 
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

$data = $_POST[ 'data1' ];
parse_str($data, $output);
$var1 = $output['var1'];
$var2= $output['var2'];

if ($output["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    $output["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}

if ($response != null && $response->success) {
//insert data into db ...
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode(
            array("message1" => 'message1',
                  "message2" => 'message2')
    )
} else {
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode(
            array("message1" => 'error reCAPTCHA')
}
```

Comment: `error php return echo message that there is an error (it doesn't return an ERROR to ajax). So the ajax is still "success".` this is incorrect terminology. Anything you echo or output is returned to the AJAX callback, success or failure of the AJAX call depends on the server handling the request such as a 404 error.  Rather or not there is an application error is much different then a request error.  I get what you are saying and your mostly right, but the way you put it seems to indicate that you don't fully understand the difference between a request error and an application error.

Comment: I understands the terminology now, didn't know how to express previously. So, after AJAX callback and second form submit, if there is no `grecaptcha.reset()` in the AJAX `$response != null && $response->success` returns `false in` php.

Comment: I point this out because it's entirely possible and appropriate to check within the success callback for application errors and then act accordingly.  For example you could return `{'error' : 'validation_error'}` and then check in the success `if(response.error)`  and then modify the behavior of things.  I imagine right now this causes some javascript errors when you get it as a response `echo "reCAPTCHA error";` because `response.message1` is undefined.

Comment: I don't use ReCaptcha, nor have I done anything with anything similar in about 5 years as these days all the stuff I do that people can submit things to are behind login systems.  So I wish I could help you more, but basically you need a way to know when validation failed (on the client side) so you can change how the UI responds to the next submission.

Comment: One option, of course, is to validate the form clientside or with an entirely separate AJAX script (that does it in real time, or before submission), an then prevents the initial form submission all together.  Thereby making 2 submissions moot for the validation issue.

Comment: I have validated `grecaptcha.getResponse()` on the client side and server side. It is always the same. On the first form submit everything is fine. But, on the second form submit (if there are errors in the fields) validation of the recaptcha in the php returns false.

Comment: My point was why are you submitting it 2x, you can stop the submission on the client side when validation fails and only submit it when you know its good.

Comment: Thank you for you advise. After a good sleep I understand the reCAPTHCA error and fix it in a blink.

Comment: Sure, I hope I at least helped you think about the problem a different way.  Sometimes it just takes a different perspective.  It's also good to take a break and come back to it (my wife tells me the same thing when I get frustrated with a coding problem, lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thaks [ArtisticPhoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3684882/artisticphoenix) for the good advise. After further investigating the same reCAPTCHA response cannot be validated twice. Changes in php fields validation have fixed my issue.